# How to code polymorphic functions under Haskell 98

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, flexibility

As a training exercise, I have written a polymorphic function to determine whether a given number is prime to either a single number or all of a list of numbers:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
class PrimeTo a where
    ispt :: Integer -> a -> Bool
instance PrimeTo (Integer) where
    ispt n d = 0 /= (rem n d)
instance PrimeTo ([Integer]) where
    ispt n [] = True
    ispt n (x:xs) = (ispt n x) && (ispt n xs)
```

To get this to work, I had to use FlexibleInstances, and I'm happy with that, but curious.

Under strict Haskell 98, as I understand it, I would need to add a type descriptor, *T*, to the instance definitions:

```
class PrimeTo a where
    ispt :: Integer -> a -> Bool
instance PrimeTo (T Integer) where
    ispt n d = 0 /= (rem n d)
instance PrimeTo (T [Integer]) where
    ispt n [] = True
    ispt n (x:xs) = (ispt n x) && (ispt n xs)
```

but I haven't a clue what goes in place of "T", and I don't even know whether this is possible under Haskell 98.

So:

1. Is this even possible under Haskell 98?
2. If so, what would be used for T?

Comment: FYI, the instance for `[Integer]` can be simplified to `ispt = all . ispt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`T` can be `Integer` or `[]`, as folllows:

```
class PrimeTo a where
    ispt :: Integer -> a -> Bool
instance PrimeTo Integer where
    ispt n d = 0 /= (rem n d)
instance PrimeToList a => PrimeTo [a] where
    ispt = isptList  -- see below
```

Since the last one can only be about `[a]`, we need a helper class `PrimeToList`.
Here's the additional helper class and instance:

```
class PrimeToList a where
    isptList :: Integer -> [a] -> Bool

instance PrimeToList Integer where
    isptList n []     = True
    isptList n (x:xs) = ispt n x && isptList n xs
```

By the way, I'd rewrite the last definition using `all`:

```
    isptList n = all (ispt n)
```

The above shows the general technique. In your specific case, you can probably avoid the helper class and use

```
class PrimeTo a where
    ispt :: Integer -> a -> Bool
instance PrimeTo Integer where
    ispt n d = 0 /= (rem n d)
instance PrimeTo a => PrimeTo [a] where
    ispt n = all (ispt n)
```

This will also define `PrimeTo [[Integer]]`, `PrimeTo [[[Integer]]]` and so on, so it is not a perfect replacement like the previous one.

Comment: The previous one also defines those instances—with unsatisfiable constraints.